# Automl Vision Error - No valid preprocessed examples

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have set up an Image classification (Single-label).

The model trained for 18 min 25 sec before I recieved the following error:

Due to one or more errors, this training job was canceled on Jan 11, 2022 at 07:34AM
Batch prediction job GAF-prediction-test encountered the following errors:
No valid preprocessed examples.

There is no documentation that I could find that explains this error type. Anyone with any ideas what this means?

Comment: Just to clarify, how did you encounter the error "No valid preprocessed examples"? Is it from running the training or doing batch prediction? The error you have shared is quite confusing.

Comment: Also if possible, if your images do not contain sensitive information. Can you host the images somewhere so they can be downloaded and the issue can reproduced by the community?

Comment: @RiccoD it was running a batch prediction. We had already trained the model. It was using the API to make the batch prediction if that is any help.

Comment: Just saw that you also created an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/214091420) for this. I checked the files you have uploaded an I noticed that in your batch prediction file, it is referencing to mp4 files. As per [preparing image data](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/prepare-image#single-label-classification) mp4 is not supported for prediction. Can you try images in a different format as mentioned in the document above?

Comment: There’s the error. Thanks. We’d not coded the JSON file to pick up the .png files. It was pointing to the .mp4 files also in the same directory. 

Possibly the error “no valid preprocessed examples” could have the further line “check your dataset and input  files to ensure valid image types are being processed” would make it a little clearer where the error is. Im sure I won’t be the last one with this mistake!

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed with @ByronRogers, the error **"No valid preprocessed examples"** is caused by incompatible input files used for batch prediction.

In this case, the model is trained using AutoML Vision and tried to perform batch prediction using .mp4 files as input files which are not supported by AutoML Vision models, hence the error above.

The resolution is to use one of the following supported image formats as input for prediction. See [preparing image data](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/prepare-image#single-label-classification) document for more details.

> Prediction data: The following image formats are supported when requesting a prediction from (querying) your model. Maximum file size is 1.5MB
>
> - JPEG
> - GIF
> - PNG
> - WEBP
> - BMP
> - TIFF
> - ICO